# Troubleshooting python serial communication

Tags: python, serial-port, port, pyserial

I am trying to use a python script to control a rotating valve. I am able to do so through PuTTY but not using my script. Code is shown below. I also included PuTTY settings and a link to the valve positioner user manual that gives example commands.

```py
import serial

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = 'COM7'
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.bytesize = serial.SEVENBITS
ser.parity = serial.PARITY_ODD
ser.xonxoff = 0
ser.rtscts = 0
ser.dsrdtr = 0
ser.stopbits = 1
ser.timeout = 1
ser.open()

if ser.isOpen():
    print(ser.name + ' is open...')
    while True:
        cmd = input("Enter command or 'exit':")
        if cmd == 'exit':
            ser.close()
            break
        else:
            # ser.write(cmd.encode('ascii'))
            # ser.write(bytes(cmd, 'utf-8'))
            ser.write(str.encode(cmd))
            out = ser.readline()
            print('Receiving... ' + str(out))
```

[image: PuTTY Settings 1]

[image: PuTTY Settings 2]

[image: User Manual]

[image: PuTTY Settings 3]

Comment: Did you mean to send: `cmd + '\n'`?

Comment: Is that necessary? I just tried it and it didn't resolve the issue

Comment: The manual mentions the command ending in `<CR>`

Comment: Have you tried running the Python script against COM1 to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: You could also try `cmd + '\r\n'` to make it the same as the `PUTTY` setting of `Implicit LF in every CR`

Comment: I used COM7 in PuTTY as well, the screenshot is wrong sorry.  Will try adding \r\n when I’m back in the office, thanks.

Comment: I added cmd +'\r\n' and it works now. Thanks!

Comment: I'll add my suggestion as an answer so you can up vote me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual that you link to says that it needs a `<CR>` at the end of each command.

Also your `putty` configuration says that it adds `crlf`.

You could change your code like this:

```py
ser.write(str.encode(cmd + '\r\n'))
```